# Intel XDK: Is it possible to create a virtual storage(Sd card ) in intel xdk emulator?

Tags: emulation, intel-xdk

In eclipse we can create virtual sd card in emulator, like that is there any way in intel xdk that I can crate a virtual sd card ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not.  There is emulation for the Filesystem API, but not specifically for an SD card.